# What does a negative frequency (omega) of vibration of atoms in a 1-D Crystal Lattice mean?

Tags: classical-mechanics, frequency, crystals, phonons

Assuming that the forces on an atom in a 1-D Crystal Lattice (unit cell is periodic) is due to its adjacent atoms, and behave like spring forces($F=kx$), I tried to calculate the frequency of atoms vibrating in a mode. I actually passed on the equation to Mathematica, and it gave me imaginary roots as the solution of the equation. Now, I am unaware of any frequency being imaginary. Furthermore, *I think* (though am not sure) that omega being imaginary contradicts my basic ansatz of taking the displacement of individual atom about its mean position

$$\delta(x) = A e^{-i(kx - \omega t)}$$.

Any and all help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take the real part of that expression for $\delta(x)$. The imaginary stuff is because currently $\delta$ is a complex number.

Comment: By delta, I mean to say "the displacement of the atom about its mean position". I apologize if I was ambiguous in there.

Comment: @Raj It's fine, though that's not usually the variable that's used. No ambiguity as far as I can see.